# Unity не могу вставить объект в поле скрипта объект

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть префаб, на котором висит скрипт. 
В скрипте есть поле для public GameObject scene;
в самой сцене есть объект Scene_management.
как только я выкидываю префаб на основную сцену и в инспекторе вставляю в скрипт, он вставляется. я сохраняю измененный префаб.и удаляю его со сцены. Но когда я заново выкидываю префаб  на сцену. в поле GameObject scene ни чего нет.
скрипт висит еще на нескольких префабах, но даже если я выкидываю на основную сцены все префабы содержащие этот скрипт и одновременно вставляю туда и все префабы сохраняю то тоже результат.
Помогите начинающему программисту.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это особенность Unity, если вам так угодно. "Префаб" - это шаблон объекта, когда вы выкидываете объект на сцену - вы создаёте экземпляр этого префаба.

Объекты на сцене существуют только в рамках сцены, а вот "префаб" существует в рамках файловой системы, в рамках сцены существуют только его экземпляры. Ссылки из файловой системы на сцену невозможны потому, что сцена непостоянна.

В итоге вы можете назначит объект со сцены в созданный экземпляр, но не можете назначит его в сам "префаб-шаблон".

Если вашим скриптам из префабов нужен доступ к скрипту на сцене, можете использовать адаптированный под Unity паттерн Синглтон (со временем вы найдете более качественные решения, но для начала и простоты понимания сойдёт и такое):

```
//Класс с вашего Scene_management
public class SceneManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static SceneManager Instance { get; private set; }

    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;   
    }

    public void DuHast()
    {
        print("Du hast mich");
    }
}

//Класс с вашего префаба
public class PrefabClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Следите, чтобы обращение не происходило раньше Awake
    void Method()
    {
        SceneManager.Instance.DuHast();
    }
}
```

Другими словами, в Awake SceneManager переводит статическую ссылку на себя и с этого момента любой другой класс в игре может получит к нему доступ через эту статическую ссылку. Нужно следить, чтобы обращения не происходили раньше Awake. С этим может помочь простое правило - в Awake класс работает только со своими полями, в Start - обращается за данными наружу.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!